# How to get the name from a nixpkgs derivation in a nix expression to be used by nix-shell?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

I'm writing a .nix expression to be used primarily by `nix-shell`. I'm not sure how to do that. Note this is not on NixOS, but I don't think that is very relevant.

The particular example I'm looking at is that I want to get [this version-dependent name](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/6dae73f552f299e4be792a8f526dda98f427149e/pkgs/applications/editors/jetbrains/default.nix#L309) that looks like:

```
  idea-ultimate = buildIdea rec {
    name = "idea-ultimate-${version}";
    version = "2017.2.2"; /* updated by script */
    description = "Integrated Development Environment (IDE) by Jetbrains, requires paid license";
    license = stdenv.lib.licenses.unfree;
    src = fetchurl {
      url = "https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-${version}-no-jdk.tar.gz";
      sha256 = "b8eb9d612800cc896eb6b6fbefbf9f49d92d2350ae1c3c4598e5e12bf93be401"; /* updated by script */
    };
    wmClass = "jetbrains-idea";
    update-channel = "IDEA_Release";
  };
```

My nix expression is the following:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  stdenv = pkgs.stdenv;
  # idea_name = assert pkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate.name != ""; pkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate.name;
in rec {
  scalaEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
    name = "scala-env";
    builder = "./scala-build.sh";
    shellHook = ''
    alias cls=clear
    '';
    CLANG_PATH = pkgs.clang + "/bin/clang";
    CLANGPP_PATH = pkgs.clang + "/bin/clang++";
    # A bug in the nixpkgs openjdk (#29151) makes us resort to Zulu OpenJDK for IDEA:
    # IDEA_JDK = pkgs.openjdk + "/lib/openjdk";
    # PATH = "${pkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate}/${idea_name}/bin:$PATH";
    IDEA_JDK = /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64;
    # IDEA_JDK = /opt/zulu8.23.0.3-jdk8.0.144-linux_x64;
    # IDEA_JDK = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64;
    buildInputs = with pkgs; [
      ammonite
      boehmgc
      clang
      emacs
      jetbrains.idea-ultimate
      less
      libunwind
      openjdk
      re2
      sbt
      stdenv
      unzip
      zlib
    ];
  };
}
```

I have commented out setting `PATH` as it depends on getting `idea_name` in the `let`-clause. As an interesting side note, as is, this does not fail if I leave it uncommented but causes a very bizarre error when executing `nix-shell` about not being able to execute `bash`. I've also tried the more simple case of `let` `idea_name = pkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate.name;` but this fails later on when `idea_name` is used in setting `PATH` since `idea_name` ends up being undefined.

**Update**:

I began exploring with `nix-instantiate`, but the derivation of interest seems empty:

```
[nix-shell:/nix/store]$ nix-instantiate --eval --xml -E "((import <nixpkgs> {}).callPackage ./3hk87pqgl2qdqmskxbhy23cyr24q8g6s-nixpkgs-18.03pre114739.d0d905668c/nixpkgs/pkgs/applications/editors/jetbrains { }).idea-ultimate";  


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<expr>
  <derivation>
    <repeated />
  </derivation>
</expr>
```

Comment: I've also tried using something like `nix-shell --verbose --verbose  --verbose --verbose --verbose --verbose --show-trace ` to understand why an assertion fails, but despite the vast quantities of information printed, that information doesn't include the assertion values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intent is to get `idea-ultimate` into nix-shell environment, then just include that package to `buildInputs`. I see it's already included, so it should already be present in your `PATH`.

BTW, you can extend your `shellHook` and export PATH and other variables rather from there, where you have full bash. Why would you do it from bash? Less copying. When you specify

```
IDEA_JDK = /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64;
```

in Nix, the file /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64 get's copied to nix store and `IDEA_JDK` is set to point to file in `/nix/store`. Was that your intent?

Regarding nix-instantiate:

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E 'with import <nixpkgs>{}; idea.pycharm-community.outPath'                                                                                   
"/nix/store/71jk0spr30rm4wsihjwbb1hcwwvzqr4k-pycharm-community-2017.1"
```

but you still have to remove doublequotes (https://gist.github.com/danbst/a9fc068ff26e31d88de9709965daa2bd)

Also, nitpick, `assert pkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate.name != "";` can be dropped as it's impossible to have empty derivation name in Nix.

And another nitpick. You'll soon find very incovenient to launch IDE from shell every time. It seems a good idea to specify, that some package is used for development, but `nix-shell` doesn't work well for non-cli applications. Not to mention occasional problems with Nix GC and `nix-shell`. You'd better install IDE globally or per-user, it is better long-term solution.

---

[ADDENDUM]

You are looking for this (`dev-environment.nix`):

```
with import <nixpkgs> { };

buildEnv {
  name = "my-super-dev-env";
  paths = [
      #emacs
      nano
      idea.pycharm-community
  ];
  buildInputs = [ makeWrapper ];
  postBuild = ''
    for f in $(ls -d $out/bin/*); do
      wrapProgram $f \
        --set IDEA_JDK "/path/to/zulu-jdk" \
        --set CLANG_PATH ... \
        --set CLANCPP_PATH ...
    done
  '';
}
```

which you install using `nix-env -if ./dev-environment.nix`. It will wrap your programs with those env vars, without polluting your workspace (you can pollute it further using `nix-shell` with shell hook, if you want).

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! Is it possible to use a nix expression to specify the user environment? By the way, I wanted to get the idea path in order to run `idea.sh` directly as part of a workaround of using a different JDK than the one in nix.

Comment: @bbarker it's a tricky question, because, while it is possible in Nix, it has drawbacks. I'll add required steps to my answer then

Comment: Thanks! I am using this from a container, so In a way I view the whole thing as a transient environment.